# how to get the row containg a checked checkbox from a JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to get the values from the hidden column of a Jquery Datatables where the checkbox has been selected (in the first visible column). So far I've got

```
bodytable$ = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "bPaginate" : true,

    "bSort" : false,
    "bFilter": false,       
    "aoColumns": [{"bVisible": false},
                  {"bVisible": true},
                  {"bVisible": true},
                  {"bVisible": true}],

    "oLanguage": {
        "sEmptyTable": '',
        "sInfoEmpty": '',
        "sZeroRecords": ''
    }
});
```

and I'm getting the values from the hidden column with

```
    var checkIds = [];

    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', bodytable$.fnGetNodes()).each(function(i){
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var rowData = bodytable$.fnGetData(tr);
        checkIds.push(rowData[0]);
    });
    alert(checkIds);
```

This fails on the line 
    var rowData = bodytable$.fnGetData(tr);
with Firefox debug giving the error message TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined

I have to go through the DataTable API because the hidden column doesn't actually appear in the html loaded into the browser and, because I want to be able to select the data values when the selected checkboxes aren't on the same page.

Following on from mainguys response, and using CSS to hide the column instead of the bVisible property, I can now get what I want with;

```
    var checkIds = [];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', bodytable$.fnGetNodes()).each(function(i){
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        checkIds.push($(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text());
    });
    alert(checkIds);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a trick how to do this.

Don't hide the collumn, just assign a class with `display:none` to it.

```
"aoColumns": [{
  "bVisible": true
}, {
  "bVisible": true, sClass:"hideme"
}, {
  "bVisible": true
}]
```

CSS:

```
.hideme {
  display:none;
}
```

Now find them with this:

```
   var checkIds = [];
    bodytable$.$('tr').each(function(index,rowhtml){
      var checked= $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked',rowhtml).length;
      if (checked==1){
        checkIds.push($('.hideme',rowhtml).text());
      }
    });
    alert(checkIds);
```

Yes, i know this is not very elegant, but it works. [Try it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yoW4W1tlZdyHtwHfaFI7?p=preview)

Comment: You sir are a genius! The trick is, as you say, to hide the column with CCS rather than the dataTable bVisible property. This now leaves the column in the HTML and I've edited my question to give my final solution.